# How can I make InputBox only accept numbers

Tags: vb.net

The code is just asking for the pass rates for 6 different colleges.  The rate must be a value between 1 and 100.

I would like it to only allow numbers.  I have tried using `IsNumeric`, but I must not be using it correctly.  Here's what I have so far:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 5
    passRate(i) = InputBox("Enter the pass rate for " & colleges(i) & " college")
    While passRate(i) > 100 Or passRate(i) < 0
        MsgBox("Error must be a number and be between 0 and 100")
        passRate(i) = InputBox("Enter the pass rate for " & colleges(i) & " college")
    End While
Next i
```

Comment: Store the return in a temp var and only add it to the array if it is in range.  IsNumeric is for numerals, you will want to Parse/Convert to integer to test the *value*.  Option Strict is strongly advised: `passRate` seems to contain both strings and integers

Comment: Grouped arrarys that match on index is an anti-pattern. You should have a single array with a custom class instead.

Answer (score 1):

use this function for check value

```
Private Function IsInputNumeric(input As String) As Boolean
        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input) Then Return False
        If IsNumeric(input) Then Return True
        Dim parts() As String = input.Split("/"c)
        If parts.Length <> 2 Then Return False
        Return IsNumeric(parts(0)) AndAlso IsNumeric(parts(1))
End Function
```

and use like this

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 5

    passRate(i) = InputBox("Enter the pass rate for " & colleges(i) & " college")
    If IsInputNumeric(passRate(i)) Then
        'handle numeric input
    Else
        'handle not a number
    End If
    While passRate(i) > 100 Or passRate(i) < 0
        MsgBox("Error must be a number and be between 0 and 100")
        passRate(i) = InputBox("Enter the pass rate for " & colleges(i) & " college")

    End While
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of things to note.

1. IsNumeric does not test for just an integer.  It will return true
   for "1.5"  since it is numeric.  I am assuming that you are looking
   for an integer value of 1 to 100 as an input result.
2. An input box returns an string.  Some form of parsing (implicit or explicit)     must happen if you are going to compare it to an integer type.

To avoid that conversion you could use a simple RegEx.  This one will validate it to be an integer between 1 and 100:

```
Function IsValid(Byval inputString as String) as Boolean
    Dim validValues As New Regex("^[1-9]?[0-9]{1}$|^100$")
    Return validValues.IsMatch(inputString )
End Function
```

Admitily RegEx can be a bit much... So here is another way to check that the input string will cast to an integer and if so is it between 1 and 100 in value.

```
Function IsValid(Byval inputString as String) as Boolean
  Dim result As Boolean = False
  Dim inputAsInteger as Integer = 0
  If Integer.TryParse(value, inputAsInteger) Then
     result = inputAsInteger > 0 And inputAsInteger <= 100)
  End If
  Return result
End Function
```

You can call either of these like so:

```
   Dim validInput as Boolean = False
   While Not validInput
      validInput = IsValid(InputBox("Enter the pass rate for " & colleges(i) & " college")
   Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub txbDwellTime_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txbDwellTime.KeyPress
    pNumDecOnly(e)
    'txbDwellTime.Text = ""
End Sub

Public Sub pNumDecOnly(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)
    If (Asc(e.KeyChar) >= 48 And Asc(e.KeyChar) <= 57 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 46) Then
        'good job do nothing we only allow positive Decimal numbers in this field
        'Asc(e.KeyChar) 48 Through 57 i.e. 0 through 9 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) 46 (dot= .)
    Else
        e.Handled = True
        MsgBox("Only Positive Decimal Numbers Allowed this field")
    End If
End Sub
```

This will allow only positive Decimal numbers using the ASCII Table, you should be able to modify this for your own use