# How to handle incorrect format?

Tags: vb.net, loops, for-loop, error-handling

I've been working on a program that calculates a down payment on a house with compound interest accumulating over the years. The user gives the amount they saved, the amount of yearly interest (percent), and the number of years spent accumulating interest.

I've managed to work out the logic of this using a 'for' loop. My assignment states that I also must not accept negative numbers or letters entered into an input box. This is where I've been getting problems.

**Problem 1: If letters are entered into the "savings" input box object, The program will crash and throw the following error code: "Input string was not in correct format"...this is in reference to the following line of code:**

```
dubSavingsTotal = Convert.ToDouble(strSavingsTotal)
```

**Problem 2: When a negative number is entered into the "savings" input box, the program seems to ignore the following if statement**

```
 If dubSavingsTotal < 0 Then

 strSavingsTotal = InputBox(strErrorMessageSavings, , "")
 End If
```

Please Forgive me, but it seemed the easiest way to do this was with if/else statements, stating that if the given value was less than 0 or wasn't numeric, then a message box would appear, and the user would be prompted to enter another number in the input box.

This is what I've attempted below in my code, I have if statements meant to stop the user from entering letters or negative numbers into the savings input box. Thank you all for any and all help, its very much appreciated.

```
Option Strict On

Public Class frmhomedownpayment

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    'This Code is executed when the user clicks on the "Enter Savings Data" button
    'The user then enters the savings, interest and year values into an input box
    'The data is then displayed to the right of the application window, while the interest 
    'amounts are calculated and displayed in the listbox object. 


    'Declare Variables
    Dim dubSavingsTotal As Double
    Dim dubInterestTotal As Double
    Dim dubYearsTotal As Double
    Dim dublistTotal As Double

    Dim strSavingsTotal As String
    Dim strInterestTotal As String
    Dim strYearsTotal As String

    Dim strSavingsTotalMessage As String = "Enter your current savings"
    Dim strInterestTotalMessage As String = "Enter the annual interest amount."
    Dim strInterestTotalMessage2 As String = "The number should be entered as a percent (5 for 5%)"
    Dim strYearsTotalMessage As String = "Enter the Years"
    Dim strErrorMessageYears As String = "Data Error (Years) : Enter a Numeric Value greater than 0!"
    Dim strErrorMessageSavings As String = " Data Error (Savings) : Enter a Numeric Value greater than 0!"
    Dim strErrorMessageInterest As String = " Data Error (Interest) : Enter a Numeric Value greater than 0!"

    'Input Boxes
    strSavingsTotal = InputBox(strSavingsTotalMessage, " ")
    strInterestTotal = InputBox(strInterestTotalMessage & strInterestTotalMessage2, " ")
    strYearsTotal = InputBox(strYearsTotalMessage, " ")


    'Error Catching
    If Not IsNumeric(dubSavingsTotal) Then
        strSavingsTotal = InputBox(strErrorMessageSavings, , "")
    End If

    If dubSavingsTotal < 0 Then
        strSavingsTotal = InputBox(strErrorMessageSavings, , "")
    End If


    'Conversions to Double
    dubSavingsTotal = Convert.ToDouble(strSavingsTotal)
    dubInterestTotal = Convert.ToDouble(strInterestTotal)
    dubYearsTotal = Convert.ToDouble(strYearsTotal)


    'We want the entered number to be expressed as a percentage
     dubInterestTotal = dubInterestTotal / 100

     'Display the Data
     lblInterestTotal.Text = dubInterestTotal.ToString("P")
     lblYearTotal.Text = strYearsTotal.ToString
     lblSavingsTotal.Text = dubSavingsTotal.ToString("C")


     'A 'For' loop that calculates the interest amounts and displays them 
      to a listbox object
     ***starting from the first year***

        For dubYearsTotal = 1 To dubYearsTotal
            dublistTotal = ((dubInterestTotal * dubSavingsTotal) * 
            dubYearsTotal)
            lstTotals.Items.Add(dublistTotal + dubSavingsTotal)


        Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint at the `IF` Statement and tell us what the value of `dubSavingsTotal ` is? Maybe there is an implicit conversion somewhere during the comparison...

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. The value at breakpoint of dubSavingsTotal = 0

Comment: What has this question got to do with VBA?

Comment: @Al Capwned then you should look into your conversion, maybe trace back `dubSavingsTotal` & `strSavingsTotal` where the conversion fails.

Comment: @jmcilhinney nothing, for some reason people assume vb.net and vba is the same.

Comment: Ok, but I need the data type to be double in order for me to do math with it, hence I converted from string to double above...are you saying I need to pick different conversions?

Comment: @jmcilhinney apologies, I have removed the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1:**

- This is intended, you have to make sure to not pass invalid data (eg. String with characters in it) to the function. You could try [Double.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads) but I only got here though the VBA tag, I don't have any experience with VB.Net.
- There are also other ways to [validate if the input is a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29195423/how-can-i-make-inputbox-only-accept-numbers).

**Problem 2:**

- Obviously (refering to your comment: *The value at breakpoint of dubSavingsTotal = 0*) something went wrong during the conversion, try following back the value of `dubSavingsTotal` & `strSavingsTotal` and see where the conversion fails. maybe try Double.Parse instead.

**Example:**
As I said, I have on experience with VB.Net and no way to test this code, but it should work in theory. Sources: [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads), [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-TryParse-in-VB-NET), [Dream In Code](https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/333533-tryparse/)

```
dim someString as String
dim someDouble as Double

if Double.TryParse(someString, someDouble) then
    Console.Write("Conversion successful, converted " & someString & " to " & someDouble)
else if
    Console.Write("Conversion failed, " & someString & " could not be converted")
end if
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this, Ill review and see about parsing